# Python reading a file and iterating over it

Tags: python

Here is the file 'the_guessing_game':

```
3
2
< 100 No
> 100 No
3
< 2 Yes
> 4 Yes
= 3 No
6
< 2 Yes
> 1 Yes
= 1 Yes
= 1 Yes
> 1 Yes
= 1 Yes
```

Here is the python code:

```
infile = open("the_guessing_game")
testcases = next(infile)
print "no of testcase : %s" %(testcases)
for case in testcases:
    hints = next(infile)
    print "no of hints : %s" %(hints)
    for hint in hints:
        hint = next(infile)
        print "hint : %s" %(hint)
```

The result of above code is:

```
no of testcase : 3

no of hints : 2

hint : < 100 No

hint : > 100 No

no of hints : 3

hint : < 2 Yes

hint : > 4 Yes
```

Why doesn't it print the hints in the range of 'no. of hints' Also, 'no. of testcases' is 3 but the loop runs just twice. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
for case in testcases:
```

with:

```
for case in range(int(testcases)):
```

With the former line, the loop runs once for each character in the string contained in the variable testcases.  With the later line, the loop runs `int(testcases)` number of times.

The string testcases consists of two characters: a three and a new line: `'3\n'`.  So, in the former case, the loop runs twice, once for each character.

In some languages, like bash or tcl, a string can be used as a number, depending on context.  In python, a string is a string unless you convert it, such as with `int` or `float`.

Comment: thanks, it works. Can you explain why it wasn't doing it rightl before? I mean the no of testcases were being printed rightl as 3.

Comment: @Monique Does the newly added explanation help?